# Tiempo promedio en página de GA4 no lo encuentro en Google Data Studio

Tags: google-data-studio

Hola me gustaría traer el dato de tiempo promedio en página que veo en analytics (GA4):
[image: tiempo en página 4 minutos de ga4]

Y sin embargo no encuentro la métrica de Tiempo de interacción medio en Google Data Studio.

¿Cómo lo calcularon?

Answer (score 0):

Buenas espero llegar a tiempo! puedes sacar eso creando una métrica con un campo. Dividiendo el User Engagement / Total users.

Si tu fuente de datos esta en español la formula sería la siguiente:

Expansiones por parte de los usuarios / Total usuarios

Y si Expansiones por parte de los usuarios es el nombre de User Engagement